# Test InjectModel using Jest and nestjs-typegoose

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

My controller has a argument is a InjectModel, code:

```
 constructor(
      @InjectModel(Poll) private readonly model: ReturnModelType<typeof Poll>,
  ){
 }
```

and the Poll code is:

```
import { prop, modelOptions, getModelForClass } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import { ApiProperty, ApiPropertyOptions } from '@nestjs/swagger';

@modelOptions({
schemaOptions: {
timestamps: true
}
})
export class Poll {
@ApiProperty({

})
@prop({required: true})
title: string

@prop({required: true})
description: string

@prop()
poll: number

@prop({select: false})
userId: string

@prop()
userName: string

}
```

Jest code:

```
import { Poll } from '@libs/db/models/poll.model';
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [PollsModule],
  controllers: [PollsController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: getModelForClass(Poll),
      useValue: getModelForClass(Poll)
    },
  ]
}).compile();
```

and I get this error:
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PollsController (?). Please make sure that the argument PollModel at index [0] is available in the PollsModule context.

```
Potential solutions:
- If PollModel is a provider, is it part of the current PollsModule?
- If PollModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within PollsModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing PollModel */ ]
  })
```

Comment: Where are you getting `getModelForClass` from? If you are using `@InjectModel()` you should be using `getModelToken()` for getting the correct provider token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

poll is in a global model as 'DbModel', and DbModel is in the appModel. so the testModel need imports the DbModel, and then fix !